# Query pg_stat_user_tables across multiple databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to gather metrics for prometheus postgres exporter. It can connect only to a single db, so I'm trying to query the other with this:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        dblink(t1.connstring,
        'SELECT schemaname, relname, seq_scan, seq_tup_read, idx_scan,
        idx_tup_fetch, n_tup_ins, n_tup_upd, n_tup_del, n_tup_hot_upd, n_live_tup,
        n_dead_tup, n_mod_since_analyze, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum,
        last_analyze, last_autoanalyze, vacuum_count, autovacuum_count,
        analyze_count, autoanalyze_count FROM pg_stat_user_tables')
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 'dbname=' || datname AS connstring
        FROM pg_database
        WHERE datistemplate = FALSE 
        ) 
    AS t1
    )
AS t2(schemaname name,
    relname name,
    seq_scan bigint,
    seq_tup_read bigint,
    idx_scan bigint,
    idx_tup_fetch bigint,
    n_tup_ins bigint,
    n_tup_upd bigint,
    n_tup_del bigint,
    n_tup_hot_upd bigint,
    n_live_tup bigint,
    n_dead_tup bigint,
    n_mod_since_analyze bigint,
    last_vacuum timestamp WITH time ZONE,
    last_autovacuum timestamp WITH time ZONE,
    last_analyze timestamp WITH time ZONE,
    last_autoanalyze timestamp WITH time ZONE,
    vacuum_count bigint,
    autovacuum_count bigint,
    analyze_count bigint,
    autoanalyze_count bigint)
;
```

but getting this error:
`SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "name"`
Or maybe there is a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: no postgres will not allow that